# No zero exit status error when running install.packages on Hmisc

Tags: r, installation, package

I keep receiving the no zero exit status error whilst trying to install Hmisc, tried updating everything (OS, R studio etc), no result. Other packages run, just not this one.

This is the error i received:

Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
namespace ‘htmltools’ 0.5.6.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.7 is required
Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘htmlwidgets’

- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/htmlwidgets’
- restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/htmlwidgets’

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried updating your htmlwidgets package?

Comment: I haven't got it installed, I've tried running install.packages for HTMLwidgets but it still returns non zero exit